# How to get a Youtube channel id associated with a divice account in Android?

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I currently use a webview within the App to manage the entire process from the time the user logs-in until he chooses his youtube channel. Everything was very simple.

This is the current method that im using right now

```
login = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.login);
login.loadUrl("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
               client_id="+config.CID+"&
               redirect_uri="+config.redirect_uri+"&
               scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly&
               response_type=code&access_type=offline");
```

Works super fine, but now, Google will no longer allow OAuth requests in embedded browsers known as “web-views”. Here is the article:

https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html

So the options are the Google Sign-In button and AppAuth.

I already found this answers :

[YouTube API v3 get all channels associated with a logged in user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072799/youtube-api-v3-get-all-channels-associated-with-a-logged-in-user)

[Getting All Channels using Youtube data api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349606/getting-all-channels-using-youtube-data-api-v3)

But the link they mention shows nothing or there is no answer

By the way, i only need the channel id, The user could even enter the ID by hand, but the idea is to ensure that the channel is of his property.

I would be grateful for any kind of help.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ? I am looking everywhere and did not find anything...

Comment: Nothing yet. I had to patch the problem sent to the user outside of the App through a window of the web browser. (Using the same URL we used before) There Google initiates the authentication process, then displays on screen an ID that the user must copy for later Paste in the App.